# AD Group authorisation in MVC5 web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, asp.net-mvc-5

It was similar to the linked answer but I used the following syntax instead:

```
Ended up using [Authorize(Roles = "DOMAIN\\Group")] in the controller which worked perfectly
```

I have a web app, that I've completed now and the only things outstanding are to:

Upload to a web server;
Make it so the site is only accessible to members of an AD Group.

I've been reading various articles and they all suggest different things. I have set the windows authentication up in the MVC and it will print out the userid on the banner in form of:

DOMAIN\Username

All I want to do now, is to pass through the AD group membership. If the user is in the group they can access the site, if they aren't they won't be able to view it.

I've tried this in the web.config, which I believe should work, but isn't in the test environment (VS 2013 Exp. for Web running iisexpress):

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow roles="DOMAIN\Some Group"/>
</authorization>
```

Do I need a more complex method of doing this? At the moment I can still run and use the site despite not being in the specified AD Group.

Comment: DO NOT do this please.  The web.config authorization is absolutely not the way to deny/allow users to locations in MVC, it can easily be bypassed with incorrect code.  [Use the AuthorizeAttribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766914/authorize-an-entire-security-group-to-perform-an-action-in-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: cheers, will build it into the controller then.

Comment: Ended up using  [Authorize(Roles = "DOMAIN\\Group")] in the controller which worked perfectly.

Comment: Please take a look at [Can I Answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using `[Authorize(Roles = "DOMAIN\\Group")]` in the controller which worked perfectly.

Comment: This worked for me temporarily then just stopped working and now I get HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized unless I remove the annotation entirely.